# How do I obtain a wallet address and pool password for my config file?

Tags: monero-wallet-cli, xmr-stak-amd

I'm pretty sure I need to get my wallet address in this format:

> "YOUR_XMR_ADDRESS.YOUR_PAYMENT_ID.YOUR_WORKER/YOUR_EMAIL"

If I enter just my XMR wallet address into the "wallet address" field, and then run the miner I get a "SOCKET ERROR - no login/password specified"

I already have an XMR wallet set up, so I have my XMR address, but the rest of the line I don't know where to find

I'm not really sure how much difference which pool I join makes, but I found [this pool](https://xmrpool.net/#/help/getting_started) on moneropools.com and I wanted to join it. They have a login button but no sign up button anywhere.

I'm not particularly locked in to choosing this pool, but I've checked many others and none seem to give me a worker ID or payment ID.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually you don't need a `Payment ID` anymore nowadays for new Wallet addresses. The `Payment ID` is now included in your Wallet address.

`Worker ID` is a label you can assign freely. Like `MyWorker1`.

`Pool password` is usally just `x`

So the whole string should look like:

```
"pool_address" : "xmr-eu1.nanopool.org:14444",
"wallet_address" : "46bNjyPKJU4hjT4xJTjzALb6Ck8xZjDBcewwKBp8Uk3P4WE6F21t2gTi5P58WQwJ6dHPUNicGWx6N9fjH55DCBkz4g3S9eQ.MyWorker1/your@email.com",
"pool_password" : "x",
```

Some pools may have different configurations tho. Some - like XMRPool.net - require you to append a `fixed difficulty level` to your wallet address. Like `your_wallet_address.workerId+difficulty/your@email.com`

Please also look at the examples on the page you linked. Scroll down to `The moment`.

The `Login` is usually `Your_Wallet_Address` and the password is `your@email.com`.

Comment: The "x" in pool password solved my issue. I didn't realize that the worker ID was user defined. Thank you for the extremely clear example